# Leibniz integral rule and Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

I've got a problem with something. Actually, let $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function, continuous on $I$ ($I$ interval of $\mathbb{R}$). We know that :

$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ verify $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x,a \in I$. But, now, we have also :

$F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} 1_{[a;x]} \times f(t) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda(t)$ for all $x \in I$. And now, using the Leibniz integral rule, as we have :

- $\forall x \in I \; \;  t \rightarrow 1_{[a;x]}f(t)$ is Lebesgue-integrable as $f$ is continuous, so bounded, on $[a;x]$ ;
- The derivative of $x \rightarrow 1_{[a;x]} \times f(t)$ exists for almost all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and is equal to $0$ (cause the function is constant on $[a;x]$ and on $\ ]-\infty;a[ \cup ]x;+\infty[$) (we suppose x>a but same if a>x)

So, we should have :

$F'(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} 0 \, \mathrm{d}t = 0$, which is wrong cause we know that $F'(x) = f(x)$. But where is the mistake ?

Thank you !

Comment: It's hard to say exactly where the error is. The version of Leibniz' rule that you're applying here simply does not exist. If you state carefully and precisely the version of Leibniz that you think can be applied here someone can say which hypothesis is not satisfied - can't do that without knowing exactly what theorem you're attempting to apply.

Comment: The derivative of $S(x)=1_{[a,x]}f(t)$ isn't $0$, but $0+1_{[a,x]}f'(t)$. You have to apply the Leibniz rule: $$\frac{d}{dx}(fg)=\frac{df}{dx}g+f\frac{dg}{dx} .$$

Comment: The problem is the derivative of $1_{[a,x]}(t)$. It is not equal to $0$. Indeed, it equals a Dirac delta at $x$.

Comment: I don't understand. We have : $x \rightarrow 1_{[a;x]}(t)f(t) = f(t)$ if $x \geq t \geq a$ and $x \rightarrow 1_{[a;x]}(t)f(t) = 0$ otherwise. So as the variable is $x$, the derivating should be $0$ almost everywhere on $I$. i don't understand what's wrong here... To David C. Ullrich, I wanted to use this theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: @Choco: The derivative w.r.t. $x$ needs to exist for **all** $x$. The "almost everywhere" is only w.r.t. the integration variable. You need that for almost all $t$, the following holds: The integrand is differentiable w.r.t. $x$ everywhere.

Comment: @ChocoSavour: That's a classic confusing feature of real analysis. As PhoemueX explained, the "almost-everywhere" does not go along well with differentiation, unlike integration. See, for example, Rudin "Real and complex analysis", 3rd ed, pag. 144, §7.16: "The fundamental theorem of calculus", especially example (b).